# ModSecurity: Execution phases can only be specified by chain starter rules

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, mod-security, mod-security2

In modsecurity default-script:

```
base_rules/modsecurity_crs_20_protocol_violations.conf
```

there is a rule, 960011:

```
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "^(?:GET|HEAD)$" \
  "msg:'GET or HEAD Request with Body Content.',\
  severity:'2',\
  id:'960011',\
  ver:'OWASP_CRS/2.2.9',\
  rev:'1',\
  maturity:'9',\
  accuracy:'9',\
  phase:1,\
  block,\
  logdata:'%{matched_var}',\
  t:none,\
  tag:'OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/INVALID_HREQ',\
  tag:'CAPEC-272',\
  chain"
    SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Length "!^0?$"\
      "t:none,\
      setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',\
      setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score},\
      setvar:'tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/INVALID_HREQ-%{matched_var_name}=%{matched_var}'"
```

I only want to disable logging for this rule (it gives too many false positives),
and therefore add my own script

```
base_rules/z99_logging_suppress.conf
```

to **remove** the default-rule and **create a new** identical rule -- only **without logging**:

```
SecRuleRemoveById 960011

SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "^(?:GET|HEAD)$" \
  "msg:'GET or HEAD Request with Body Content.',\
  severity:'2',\
  id:'9960011',\
  ver:'OWASP_CRS/2.2.9',\
  rev:'1',\
  maturity:'9',\
  accuracy:'9',\
  phase:1,\
  block,nolog,\
  logdata:'%{matched_var}',\
  t:none,\
  tag:'OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/INVALID_HREQ',\
  tag:'CAPEC-272',\
  chain"
    SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Length "!^0?$"\
      "t:none,\
      setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',\
      setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score},\
      setvar:'tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/INVALID_HREQ-%{matched_var_name}=%{matched_var}'"
```

The only differences to the original rule are the **new id 9960011**, and the **nolog** additions:

```
  ...
  id:'9960011',\
  ...
  block,nolog,\
  ...
```

But when I restart httpd with this additional rule, I get error:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 18 of /path/base_rules/z99_logging_suppress.conf:
ModSecurity: Execution phases can only be specified by chain starter rules.
```

The same strategy --- SecRuleRemoveById + then re-create it with new id --- works for all other default-rules I tried, but not for this one.

Anyone can tell me why that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically says that the `phase` command can only be in the first rule in a chain and not in a subsequent rule which forms part of the chain.

There is nothing wrong with the rule as you have written it, phase is only specified in the first `SecRule`. In fact I've tried it on my instance and it works. So either one of two things has gone wrong:

1. You have copied and pasted it incorrectly into this question.
2. The rule above where you have defined this, has chain in it and so has left an open chain, that your rule 9960011 is then effectively trying to continue on from.

Or something else weird is happening! But I'm going with 1 or 2 for now :-)

Comment: Are u saying the above works for you with the default base-rules? hmm... Your pt 1: For that to be true I would have it wrong on the server, but got it correct in this post -- extremely unlikely since I copied from the server into here :) -- Re pt 2: To debug, I tried with only the mod-security base_rules plus the above rule, and still got the error.... I'm really confused if this actually worked for you :) ---
But I will check if I have maybe not the latest version of mod-security and/or apache.

Comment: For pt 2 it depends where you have above config? Have you pasted it after opening a previous chain?

Comment: No, I still got the error when I only added the above script to base_rules. Nothing else, other than the default base_rules files.

Comment: There's a bug saying ModSecurity doesn't alert when an open chain is left: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/issues/1042. So possibly you (or the CRS!) have an open chain somewhere but haven't noticed it before?

Comment: You are entirely correct! 
I was more confused than I thought, and apparently had not tested what I thought I had tested :/ -- Yes, turned out there was an open chain in a previous file that caused the problem. 
It's working now :) Much thanks for your help!!

Comment: Good stuff. Can recommend this book enough btw: https://www.feistyduck.com/books/modsecurity-handbook/. Written by the original author of ModSecurity and updated recently by a guy who's very active on the CRS mailing list: https://lists.owasp.org/mailman/listinfo/owasp-modsecurity-core-rule-set